# My while loop won't exit JAVA with scanner

Tags: java, while-loop

I have it working some what but it is not fully working i need to recieve and input of
4 --> This line is the number of numbers in the next line.
2 4 5 6 --> the inputs

A requirement is that say if the bottom line had 5 numbers it shows error but i keep getting into an infinite loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sequ{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            //To see if they are integers
            //Prepare the scanner 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Read the inputs
            boolean error_input = false;
            int k = 0;
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int counter = 0; 
            int[] inputs = new int[n];
            if (n <= 0) {      
                valid_input = true;
            }

            else {
                //Add try catch for too long a list
                while (scan.hasNext()){
                    int val = scan.nextInt();
                    if (val >= 0){
                        inputs[k] = val;
                        
                        if (k > 1){
                            if (inputs[k] <= inputs[k-1]){
                                ordinary_order = true;
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        error_input = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

There is more below that doesn't matter but the while loop

Comment: The only way to exit the loop is for `hasNext` to return `false` or for you to `break`, and the `break` you have is in case the number you read is negative. Seems to me like a `for` loop with an upper limit on `n` and an `if(!scan.hasNext()) break;` would have been more readable and easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question. it's code should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sequ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prepare the scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Read the number of input numbers
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        // Check for invalid input
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            return;
        }

        // Read the input numbers
        int[] inputs = new int[n];
        int numInputs = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext() && numInputs < n) {
            int val = scan.nextInt();
            if (val >= 0) {
                inputs[numInputs] = val;
                numInputs++;

                if (numInputs > 1 && inputs[numInputs - 1] <= inputs[numInputs - 2]) {
                    System.out.println("Input numbers not in increasing order.");
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Check for incomplete input
        if (numInputs < n) {
            System.out.println("Incomplete input.");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to see also say if the input value was 3 then 5 inputs are submitted to get an invalid input.